# Find radius of convergence of power series, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty ((n!)^k x^n) / (kn)!$

Tags: calculus

$k$ is a positive integer. I did the $|a_{n+1}/a_n|$ method and I'm having trouble simplifying down. I got
 $(n+1)^k x(kn)! /(kn+k)!$.

Comment: After 6 months being a member and 24 questions asked, it'd seem just convenient you'd finally learn the easy rules to write properly mathematics in this site, don't you think? For example, read http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Note that $\frac{(kn+k)!}{(kn)!}=(kn+1)(kn+2)\cdots(kn+k)$.

Comment: Start easy: let $k=1$.  What does this mean for $x$?  Does it change for $k\gt 1$?

Answer (score 2):

We have $\frac{(kn+k)!}{(kn)!}=(kn+1)(kn+2)\cdots (kn+k)$. So using your notation we obtain
that
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{|x|}{w_n},$$
where 
$$w_n=\frac{kn+1}{n+1}\cdot \frac{kn+2}{n+1}\cdots \frac{kn+k}{n+1}.$$
As $n\to\infty$, $w_n\to k^k$.